# NGINX - How to deny direct access to a file

Tags: nginx

Is there any way to prevent direct access to a file but allow it to be loaded from another page? For example, I have an swf in mydomain.com/assets/importantasset.swf and I want to load it in mydomain.com/page, but if people try to directly access that swf they will be shown a 403 error. I know there is a way to accomplish this in IIS, if anyone can convert the following code to be compatible for nginx.

```
<rule name="protect" stopProcessing="true">
<match url=".*\.(swf)$" negate="false" />
    <conditions>
    <add input="(HTTP_REFERER}" pattern="^http://domainname.com/.*$" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
<action type="AbortRequest" />
</rule>
```

Comment: No, there is no reliable way to do this and no point. (Attempts are a very good way to annoy your users, though.)

Comment: I updated the original post.